# Importing other libraries when using Swift as a scripting language

Tags: swift, swift2, swifty-json

Heyo. I'm using Swift to make a simple web crawler for fun and practice. I made an Project.swift file and added it to a folder on my desktop. I now want to add SwiftyJSON to my project. I tried putting SwiftyJSON.swift in the same folder and adding `import SwiftyJSON` on top, but this did nothing. No import statement does not work at all. Is there any way to do this except pasting the whole file to the bottom of my project.swift file, or should I just stick to Python?

Comment: Also, keep working on Swift if you like it- Python is similar. I use pods because I (had) the same issue as you at first. Don't stop Swift!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start from the file named `main.swift` - that's your application entry point:

```
// main.swift
import Foundation

let data = "{\"message\" : \"Hello World\"}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let myJson = JSON(data:data!)

print(myJson["message"])
```

So you don't have to use `include`, but you'll need to specify all external dependencies when compiling:

```
swiftc SwiftyJSON.swift main.swift
./main
```

If you're using XCode `Command Line Tool` template, main.swift will be created for you by default, and you'd be able add more .swift files to your project and just use them, no need to use `import`.